# Download PDF Content into String With Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, pdf

I'm writing a web site bot to get information multiple web sites. I'm using Selenium in c#.

But, i can not read this page's content.

Do you have any idea about how to read page content?

Thank you.

[image: Page's client side code.]

[image: Here are the pages secreen and pages codes.]

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a PDF file you can't read this page content unless you find a way to convert it to txt/docs/xls file.
It will be a hard task to find a stable service that will successfully convert 100% of your PDF's